# ActiveMQ: Transport Connector could not be registered in JMX: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [stomp]

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic, jmx

We are updating a Java app from Java 7 to 8.  As part of this we are updating ActiveMQ from 5.7 to 5.14.4 and Apache Camel from 2.12.2 to 2.18.3.

The application builds without any errors but fails at start up.  Initially I was getting this exception:

> nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBPersistenceAdapter

So I added activemq-kahadb-store to the pom.xml & now i get this exception:

> Transport Connector could not be registered in JMX:
>   java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [stomp]

Below are the activemq & camel config settings that works fine for Java 7 & the previous libraries. What do I need to change to get past this error?

```
   <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>classpath:xxx.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="broker" class="org.apache.activemq.xbean.BrokerFactoryBean">
        <property name="config" value="classpath:activemq.xml" />
        <property name="start" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="ProcessManager" class="com.xxx.boot.ProcessManager" />


           <bean id="shutdown" class="org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy">  
        <property name="timeout" value="30"/>
        </bean> 

    <bean id="XXXService" depends-on="broker" class="com.xxx.boot.ProcessExecuter" destroy-method="shutdownProcess">
        <property name="executableArguments">
            <array>
            <value>${JAVA_JDK_LOCATION_32BIT}</value>
            <value>-Xmx512M</value>
            <value>-Djava.library.path={web.directory}\\WEB-INF\\lib</value>
            <value>-Dactivemq.url.stomp=${activemq.url.stomp}</value>
            <value>-Dactivemq.url.openwire=${activemq.url.openwire}</value>
            <value>-cp</value>
            <value>{web.directory}\\WEB-INF\\lib\\*</value>
            </array>
        </property>
        <property name="executableClass">
            <value>boot.RunnerImpl</value>
        </property>
        <property name="executableDirectory">
            <value>WEB-INF/lib</value>
        </property>
        <property name="processManager">
            <ref bean="ProcessManager" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="ProcessManagerContext" trace="false" useMDCLogging="true">

        <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="classpath:xxx.properties"/>

        <route id="boot.XXXService" autoStartup="true">
            <from uri="timer://XXXService?repeatCount=1&amp;delay=5000" />
            <to uri="bean:XXXService?method=terminate" />
            <multicast parallelProcessing="true">
                <to uri="direct:startXXXService" />
                <to uri="direct:startXXXService" />
            </multicast>
        </route>

        <route id="boot.XXXService.start">
            <from uri="direct:startXXXService" />
            <to uri="bean:XXXService?method=start" />
        </route>    

        <route id="JMS.ProcessManager">
            <from uri="ir.activemq.broker.client:topic:xxx.ProcessManager?concurrentConsumers=1&amp;exchangePattern=InOnly"/>
            <filter>
                <method ref="ProcessManager" method="destinationFilter" />
                <to uri="bean:ProcessManager?method=doProcess&amp;cache=true" />
            </filter>       
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article explains the issue: http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-580-release.html.  I already had the 1st two activemq dependencies.  I needed to add dependencies for activemq-kahadb-store & activemq-stomp

```
    <!-- ActiveMQ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.activemq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.activemq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-kahadb-store</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.activemq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-stomp</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.activemq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Adding only activemq-stomp and activemq-kahadb-store is already enough.